# AS3 font embed from resource file not working

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, fonts, embed

I've done alot of searching on this and not been able to find a solution yet, I hope the board here might help me.

I have set up a project (in the same way I have numerous projects before) that uses a seperate fonts SWF to provide the fonts to my project. Once loaded I register these fonts to the global font directory using Font.registerFont(). My text styles come from an externally loaded style sheet.

For some reason that I cannot figure out, when I try to create a textField and use my embedded fonts the text disapears from screen. If when creating the textField I set embedFonts to false then the text does appear at the right size and colour (as taken from the stylesheet), but obviously with a default system font where my nice custom font should be.

The code I am using is below:

```
TTWTextHelper.traceAvailableFonts();
TTWTextHelper.traceStyleSheet(myStyleSheet);

var myText = new TextField;
with (myText)
{
     width = 250;

     autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

     selectable = false;

     antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
     styleSheet = myStyleSheet;
     embedFonts = true;
     border = true;

     multiline = true;
     wordWrap = true;

     htmlText = "<span class='body'>Test</body>";
}
myText.x = 300;
myText.y = 300;
addChild(myText);
```

I know that (apparently) my fonts are embeded as when I run TTWTextHelper.traceAvailableFonts() i get the two fonts listed.

```
public static function traceAvailableFonts():void
{
   /*
    * See what fonts we have to play with
    */

   var embeddedFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(false);
   embeddedFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);

   trace("how many fonts? " + embeddedFonts.length);
   Tools.pr(embeddedFonts); 
}
```

results in:

```
how many fonts? 2
(array) {
 [0] => (object) [object MarkerFeltThinPlain]
 [1] => (object) [object MarkerFeltWidePlain]
}
```

and I know that my styleSheet is loaded and is being correctly parsed by actionscript as when i run TTWTextHelper.traceStyleSheet(myStyleSheet); i get the styles listed out correctly:

```
public static function traceStyleSheet(_styleSheet:StyleSheet):void
{
   trace("Tracing StyleSheet: " + _styleSheet);

   var styles:Array = _styleSheet.styleNames;

   for each(var style : * in styles)
   {
     trace("Style Name: " + style);
     var thisStyle:Object = _styleSheet.getStyle(style);
     Tools.pr(thisStyle); 
   }
}
```

results in:

```
Tracing StyleSheet: [object StyleSheet]
Style Name: a
(object) {
    [color] => (string) #ff0000
    [leading] => (string) 2
    [fontFamily] => (string) "MarkerFeltThin-Plain"
    [fontSize] => (string) 15
    [textAlign] => (string) left
}

Style Name: .title
(object) {
    [color] => (string) #ff0000
    [leading] => (string) 2
    [fontFamily] => (string) "MarkerFeltWide-Plain"
    [fontSize] => (string) 20
    [textAlign] => (string) left
}

Style Name: .body
(object) {
    [color] => (string) #4b4b4b
    [leading] => (string) 2
    [fontFamily] => (string) "MarkerFeltThin-Plain"
    [fontSize] => (string) 15
    [textAlign] => (string) left
}
```

Any advise very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I've done a bit more playing on this... and come across an extra-ordinary problem / solution to this... I work on a MAC CS5, when publishing my fonts.swf file I've noticed that if the font name (not linkage or class name, but font name) has more than one word or any punctuation in its title, then it won't work in my project. For example "Arial" or "Century" or "Hurculanum" all work, where "MarkerFeltThin-Plain" or "Stencil Std" or "Co Headline Bd" don't. There is a mix of TrueType and OpenTypes in both those lists. Here is the kicker, I create the same file on PC CS3 and everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for your fonts fontType property, if the fontType property is "embeddedCFF" , they will not display with a TextField as you would need the Flash Text Engine to render.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, how do I access that? Is it an actionscript thing? Is there a way I can adjust that property?

Comment: In your embeddedFonts Array, trace the fontType property for each Font object.

Comment: Interesting... I've done this and all my fonts (both those that work and those that don't) are showing as "embedded", not "embeddedCFF"... so it would seem it should work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes embedding font files with [Embed] instead of swf helps (ran into that recently).